# how to do a replace within a replace match using vba regex

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I need to replace some characters, but only when they are within brackets. So assume following example

```
this is a string (with comment), this is another string without comment, and this is a string (with one comment, and another one)
```

I need to be able to split this sentence based on the comma value. Which would work out fine apart from the annoying fact the last comment also contains a comma so my split is a bit limited. The desired result would have to be as follows

```
this is a string (with comment), 
this is another string without comment, 
and this is a string (with one comment, and another one)
```

I'm using access VBA, and my approach was to first isolate all the comments (content within brackets), replace the comma with a different character (say the pipe symbol) and than use the split or replace options to split the whole sentence.

What I tried is something as below, but I fail to deal with the regex match like I like to. Any alternative, or insight on how I can tacklle it best ?

```
Function commentFixer(s As String, t As String) As String

't = token to be replaced, eg a comma

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim match As String
regEx.Global = True
p = "(\([^()]*\)*)"
'match all commented substrings
regEx.Pattern = p 

'below obviously doesn't work, as the match itself is not accepted as a character. Any way to deal with this ?

match = "$1" 'How can I store this in a variable to perform a replacement on the result ?
dim r as string 'replacement value

r = Replace(match, t, "|")

commentFixer = regEx.Replace(s, r)

End Function

Sub TestMe()

s = commentFixer("this is a string (with comment), this is another string without comment, and this is a string (with one comment, and another one)", ",")
Debug.Print s

'expected result : this is a string (with comment), this is another string without comment, and this is a string (with one comment| and another one)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
(.*?,)\s*(?![^()]*\))|(.+)$
```

Group index 1 and 2 contains the strings you want.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aP7aD5/3)

Comment: Thanks Raj, unfortunatly this doesn't work within VBA since it doesn't like matches without actual content (I guees, not a real expert tbh) . Regex.split isn't supported within VBA, and that's making it more complex